# Fire journey via Rest API - Shared Data Extension issue

Tags: rest-api, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am trying to use rest api to fire the journey.
The code is in cloud page , coded by ssjs.
I have successfully triggered the journey , if the target data extension is in the child business unit. but if I use the data extension in shared folder, then it doesn't work, show erorr 500.

I have tried both legacy package and new package for the installed packages.
Both are not working if the data extension is a shared one.

Also i did the test from Postman, it's working even it's a shared data extension. but once try to trigger from landing page, then failed.

Anyone could be help please.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue.Nothing wrong with the api trigger.
The problem is from the ampscript that i use for getting the value from form.
need use ent.data_extension. forgot to add 'ENT.'